# Create a Second C++ Project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am looking for detailed steps to create a second Static Lib Project in `Visual Studio 2010`
that my first project will reference.

This project will be in source control and used by others so the referencing needs to be able to work on all folder structures. (if possible)

I have done this before but have had problems recently. I mostly end up adding random references to everything and every folder in my project until it works as I do not know the correct steps to accomplish it.

This will be my projects folder structure

`<Whatever Structure>/MyProject/MainProject`
`<Whatever Structure>/MyProject/SecondProject`
`<Whatever Structure>/MyProject/MyProject.sln`

I need my `SecondProject` to be built as a Static Lib library.
Inside my `FirstProject` I would like to reference files from my `SecondProject` as

`#include <SecondProject/<filename or class or namespace>`

As I said above Detailed Steps to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.
I have searched many other posts but most just pertain to Header Files or they are half the steps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include` is solely used for headers. This is parsed at compile time. Since you want to use headers from `<Whatever>/MyProject/SecondProject` as just `SecondProject/`, obviously `<Whatever>/MyProject/` must be among the include directories. Probably the best way to specify it would be as just `../`, because that means you don't have to hardcode `<Whatever>`

After compiling, the next step is linking. The easiest solution here is to go the the property pages of `MainProject`, Common Properties > Frameworks & References, and use [Add New Reference...] button. Linking will make the compiled functions inside the .lib available.